# Error Create a Jenkins Credential with Ansible

Tags: json, jenkins, ansible, roles, credentials

I have a problem with a role to create user in jenkins with credentials plugin using private key in body.
I can get the crumb however when I make the request to create the credential I get the invalid crumb error.

My role:

```
- name: Get Jenkins Crumb
  uri:
    url: "{{ master_url }}/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,\":\",//crumb)"
    user: '{{ master_username }}'
    password: "my_token"
    method: GET
    return_content: yes
    force_basic_auth: yes
    body_format: form-urlencoded
  register: crumb

- debug:
    msg: "{{ crumb.content.split(':')[1]}}"

- name: Add credential to Node
  uri:
    url: "{{ master_url }}/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials"
    user: "{{ master_username }}"
    password: "my_token"
    method: POST
    status_code: 302
    body_format: form-urlencoded
    headers:
      Jenkins-Crumb: "{{ crumb.content.split(':')[1]}}"
      Cookie: "{{ crumb.set_cookie }}"
    body: |
      json={
        "": "0",
        "credentials": {
          "scope": "GLOBAL",
          "id": "jenkins_linux_slave1_auth",
          "username": "jenkins",
          "password": "jenkins",
          "privateKeySource": {
            "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$DirectEntryPrivateKeySource",
            "privateKey": "{{ private_key_file['content'] | b64decode | to_json}}"
          },
          "description": "Jenkins Linux Slave1 Authentication",
          "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey"
        }
      }
```

Out \ Error:

```
TASK [jenkins : Get Jenkins Crumb] *********************************************
ok: [protheus]

TASK [jenkins : debug] *********************************************************
ok: [protheus] => {
    "msg": "f87df3f83a7ecfb5f5b2e7af0c0beb218dd239ec460fba832ff36f0a90e42287"
}

TASK [jenkins : Add credential to Node] ****************************************
fatal: [protheus]: FAILED! => {"cache_control": "must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content": "<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\"/>\n<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>\n</head>\n<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</h2>\n<table>\n<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials</td></tr>\n<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>403</td></tr>\n<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>No valid crumb was included in the request</td></tr>\n<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>Stapler</td></tr>\n</table>\n<hr><a href=\"http://eclipse.org/jetty\">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.27.v20200227</a><hr/>\n\n</body>\n</html>\n", "content_length": "593", "content_type": "text/html;charset=iso-8859-1", "elapsed": 0, "msg": "Status code was 403 and not [302]: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden", "redirected": false, "server": "Jetty(9.4.27.v20200227)", "status": 403, "url": "http://192.168.0.120:9080/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials", "x_content_type_options": "nosniff"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
protheus                   : ok=9    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not calling the API, you can remove the `Jenkins-Crumb` header and use the username and the username Token.
Also add the option     `force_basic_auth: true`

So your task will be like this:

```
- name: Add credential to Node
  uri:
    url: "{{ master_url }}/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials"
    user: "{{ master_username }}"
    password: "my_token"
    method: POST
    status_code: 302
    body_format: form-urlencoded
    force_basic_auth: true
    body: |
      json={
      "": "0",
      "credentials": {
      "scope": "GLOBAL",
      "id": "jenkins_linux_slave1_auth",
      "username": "jenkins",
      "password": "jenkins",
      "privateKeySource": {
        "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$DirectEntryPrivateKeySource",
        "privateKey": "{{ private_key_file['content'] | b64decode | to_json}}"
      },
      "description": "Jenkins Linux Slave1 Authentication",
      "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @sadok-f

After modifying the task to the one suggested by you, I received the following error:


"msg": "Status code was 500 and not [302]: HTTP Error 500: Server Error", "redirected": false, "referrer_policy": "same-origin", "server": "Jetty (9.4.27. v20200227) "," set_cookie ":" JSESSIONID.af9bf050 = node0uhw0itxug8m42mnhpspodrxe3.node0; Path = /; HttpOnly "," status ": 500," url ":" http://192.168.0.120:9080/credentials/store / domain / _ / createCredentials ","

Comment: The problem now seems to be in the way I am passing the private key, in this line:

"privateKey": "{{private_key_file ['content'] | b64decode | to_json}}"

Performing a test, I removed the variable and the credential was created, but without the key.
My test went like this, and the role was successfully executed, but without the private key:
"privateKey": "foo"

How do I pass the private key for the credential to be created?

Comment: can you try to upload the file and use the source as a private key file 
`"privateKeyFile": "'{{ path_private_key_file }}.pem'",`

Comment: Use .pem, role finish ok, but jenkins node not started. Error: ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key(s) for vagrant (credentialId:app_protheus/method:publickey)
[07/01/20 22:29:05] [SSH] Authentication failed.

Comment: if the `{{ path_private_key_file }}.pem` exist?